# can't access to public files NODE JS

Tags: node.js, express, static

I must have made a silly mistake that I cant find out, I cant access to my public files, here is my app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const { router } = require('./routes/router');
// const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { initializeDB } = require('./database/connection');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jwt = require("express-jwt");
const jwksRsa = require("jwks-rsa");
// Load environment variables from .env
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const path = require('path');

const authConfig = {
  domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
  audience: process.env.ATUH0_API_AUDIENCE
};

const corsOptions = {
  origin : "*",
  methods: "GET,PUT,POST",
  allowedHeaders : "Origin, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Cache-Control",
  preflightContinue: false,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}

const checkJwt = jwt({
  secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
    cache: true,
    rateLimit: true,
    jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
    jwksUri: `https://${authConfig.domain}/.well-known/jwks.json`
  }),

  audience: authConfig.audience,
  issuer: `https://${authConfig.domain}/`,
  algorithm: ["RS256"]
});


const app = express();

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

console.log(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb'}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
  limit: '10mb'
}));
initializeDB();


app.use('/', checkJwt, router);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3500;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

I keep getting the message: Cannot GET /public/a.jpeg, or any other file I try to get,
the file does exist, so far I have ran out of ideas, any help apreciated, don't know whats left to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `path.resolve()`

eg:

```
app.use("/public", express.static(path.resolve(__dirname + '/public')));
```

Comment: Thanks! path.resolve solved it!, I have done other projects and never had the need for this, why was it different this time? is it a express version thing?

Comment: no idea for me, it always gives an error if path.resolve is not used

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the account you are using has rights/permission to access files
or secondly that the path you are using has been set up the right way. 
those are the most common problems with failing to access files from specific folders
thank you